# Blueprint via Compass in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, compass-sass, asset-pipeline, blueprint-css

I have successfully integrated Compass and Rails 3.1 in [this sample app](https://github.com/micahalcorn/otgapp). I am also trying to learn to use Blueprint, so I am trying to replicate [the Grid Test](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/grid.html) in the app. **So how do I include Blueprint?** The commands described [in the documentation](http://beta.compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/) are still outdated, as they do not work with the asset pipeline. Also, **how will the conditional css for internet explorer work if it is already compiled into the rest of application.css**? Thanks!

**Edit:** By following [Michael Hartl's example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#sec:13.1.4), I have successfully integrated Blueprint and the pipeline in development. But I am still not getting the appropriate styles in development, and I am also having a compile issue in production.

Comment: I ended up using [960gs](http://960.gs/) instead and am very happy.

Answer (score 1):

Do it another way :

1) add to Gemfile and run **bundle update compass**:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.alpha'
end
```

2) create a blueprint.css.scss file on app/assets/stylesheets with the following contents:

```
@import '_blueprint';
@include blueprint;
```

3) into app/assets/stylesheets/application.css have this:

```
 /*
  *= require_self
  *= require blueprint
  *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: Will the conditional ie and print styles be handled automatically?